# Do action when something is printed in System.err

Tags: java

Like in topic - I am trying to do action when anything is printed into error stream, but code below is not working:

```
try {
    System.setOut(new PrintStream("InfoLog.txt"));
    System.setErr(new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("ErrorLog.txt") {
        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            super.write(b);
            error();
        }
        public void write(byte[] b) throws IOException {
            super.write(b);
            error();
        }
    }));
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(HouseCalc.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

Is there any way to "catch" the System.err stream and make any action before it gets printed to file?

Comment: You can set the `err` with `System.setErr()`. So wrap it in your own `PrintStream` and override it so that it does something.

Comment: I am already doing this like in the example above, but this method does not work.

Comment: What doesn't work about it? You're possibly not overriding the right methods.

Comment: It seems that the "ErrorLog.txt" file is created and everything is printed to it, but both "write" methods are not called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to override **the appropriate methods**. Have a good look at the source of `PrintStream`, because they might be calling *each other*. You want to get all the way down.

```
write(char cbuf[], int off, int len)
```

might be the one you really need.